# XML Schema validation. Unordered list with indeterminate number of items

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to create an XML schema for validating the following XML using version 1.0.

Rules are

1. XML is unordered under `<host>` tag
2. `ip4`, `present`, and `hostname` are **required**
3. `comment` is not required
4. There can be any number of `hostname` elements

**example.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<host>
  <comment>List of hosts</comment>
  <hostname>nohostname1</hostname>
  <hostname>nohostname2</hostname>
  <ipv4>127.0.0.1</ipv4>
  <present>no</present>
</host>
```

I currently have...

**example.xsd**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!-- any_string_type -->
<xs:simpleType name="any_string_type">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- boolean_type -->
<xs:simpleType name="boolean_value_type">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>Boolean annotation [no/yes]</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="no"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="yes"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- ipv4 address type -->
<xs:simpleType name="ipv4_type">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>IPv4 address in dot-decimal notation [0-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255]</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>


<!-- Start of host validation -->
<xs:element name = "host">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name = "ipv4" type = "ipv4_type"/>
          <xs:element name = "comment" type = "any_string_type" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name = "present" type = "boolean_value_type"/>

          <!-- I want to say maxOccures="unbounded" but that is not valid XML schema -->
          <xs:element name = "hostname" type = "any_string_type"/> 

        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But I can't seem to get around having any number of hostname elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters your XSD isn't even valid, the `<xs:element>` just before the `</xs:schema>` should be `</xs:element>`

But yes, you can't make the hostname occur multiple times in a xsd:All. In Visual Studio (with BizTalk SDK) I get the following error.

> The {max occurs} of all the particles in the the {particle} of an all group must be 0 or 1.

You have two options.  Either change the host to be a choice with a minOccurs of 3 and a maxOccurs of unbounded.   This however won't enforce that your ip4, hostname & present occur at least once and only once for ip and present.

The other option is to change the structure of your payload and have a hostnames node  under which you have the hostname element and set that to minOccurs="1" and maxOccurs="unbounded"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="any_string_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="boolean_value_type">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Boolean annotation [no/yes]</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="no" />
      <xs:enumeration value="yes" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="ipv4_type">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>IPv4 address in dot-decimal notation [0-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255]</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="host">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="ipv4" type="ipv4_type" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="comment" type="any_string_type" />
        <xs:element name="present" type="boolean_value_type" />
        <xs:element name="hostnames">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="hostname" type="any_string_type" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the payload would look like this and validate.

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<host>
  <comment>List of hosts</comment>
  <hostnames>
      <hostname>nohostname1</hostname>
      <hostname>nohostname2</hostname>
  </hostnames>
  <ipv4>127.0.0.1</ipv4>
  <present>no</present>
</host>
```

Comment: Ended up modifying the payload coming in to nest the hostname like you have above. Thanks.